# Fabric Does not work with cocoa app - Xcode 10 beta 6

Tags: xcode, cocoa, crashlytics, google-fabric

Simply created new cocoa app, followed steps for adding fabric and it does not work.

Using Xcode 10 beta 6 and os Mojave - beta 10, I see there is one additional configuration required for Xcode 10, but does not help.

Application not showing up on Fabric Dashboard

Comment: Paul from Fabric here. Our servers need to see a build and a run event within 24 hours of each other in order to activate a new app. Did you build and run your app so that we'd activate it?

Comment: @buser, let me know which info you needed.

Comment: @buser, I am trying from last few days, but it does not work

Comment: @buser, created from Xcode 10 GM version, no luck Error is 2018-09-15 19:29:53.261820+0530 TestFabric2[12059:311336] [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-6 "(null)" UserInfo={retryLimit=1, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/mac/apps/com.funnmedia.TestFabric2/settings?build_version=1&display_version=1.0&instance=79d40b7481be05838c4fe38d436edffcb821ff52&source=1}

Comment: @buser I get the same error, copy pasting the URL into the browser yields no results